# Unable to remove white space between v-text-field and labels using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify-tabs

I'm trying to decrease huge gap between rows using vuetify but could not decrease. I tried by using css and vuetify spacing as well but doesnot work.

Expected form

[image]

Actual form
[image]

```
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="4">
      First Name
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="4">
      <v-text-field v-model="firstname" :rules="nameRules" label="first name" required class="ma-0 pa-0"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      Last Name
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field v-model="lastname" :rules="nameRules" label="Last name" required class="ma-0 pa-0"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Comment: change the column width to 3?

Comment: Sorry ! I didn't understand. @depperm

Comment: `cols="3"` instead of `cols="4"`

Comment: I got error  Trailing spaces not allowed  no-trailing-spaces. @depperm

Comment: that is not what the question says. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58794700/3462319)

Comment: cols="3" didn't solve my problem. @depperm

Comment: please edit your question to clarify what exactly is wrong. what exactly are you trying to accomplish and why what you've tried doesn't work

Comment: I have edited question. Actually I want to decrease spaces between rows. Sorry i couldn't make you understand properly. @depperm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210238/discussion-between-depperm-and-prabina-sht).

Answer (score 0):

Use classes 'ma-x' or 'pa-x' for removing extra padding and margin from row and cols where x id number from 0-12.

Please refer: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/